# Dynamics: Forces in a closed system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces

I need help with the following question:

There is painter in a crate which hangs alongside a building. When the painter pulls on the rope, the force he exerts on the floor of the crate is 300N. The masses of the painter and the crate are 75kg and 25kg respectively.

Calculate the acceleration of the crate.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a "homework like" question, we are not supposed to give you a full solution. But I will give you a hint / approach:

Draw yourself a diagram. There are several forces: the force of the rope on the painter, the force of the rope on the basket, the force of gravity on the painter, the force of gravity on the basket, and the force of the painter on the basket. Solve for the tension in the rope so the latter is 300 N. The net force on the system is now 2x the tension (from the pulley that the rope runs through) minus the gravity on painter and basket.

Answer (score -1):

If you consider the painter and crate are standing still before he pulls the rope, then you just have to solve F=ma where F is 300N and m is the mass of the system crate+painter.